# Adding an index in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe in Pandas:

```
id   animal
0    dog
0    cat
1    goat
1    cow
1    sheep
1    pig
2    lion
2    tiger
2    bear
```

I want to add a column as follows. I don't know what you call it but basically it's an index for each unique id.

```
id   animal   ix
0    dog      0
0    cat      1
1    goat     0
1    cow      1
1    sheep    2
1    pig      3
2    lion     0
2    tiger    1
2    bear     2
```

Notice how it increments going down for whenever it continues to see the same id but it resets back to 0 whenever a new id has been found. Anyone knows the best way it could be done? I was thinking of obtaining all unique id's and increment an ix for each row of the same id that I see. Is there a better way to do it? (Side note, I shouldn't call it id since it's not unique in the df but I just can't think of a better column name)

Comment: @Rodalm yes, exactly what I need. Thanks! I didn't know this function exists

Comment: No worries, glad to help! I made it an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Group by `id` and use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)

```
df['ix'] = df.groupby('id').cumcount()
```

Output:

```
>>> df

   id animal  ix
0   0    dog   0
1   0    cat   1
2   1   goat   0
3   1    cow   1
4   1  sheep   2
5   1    pig   3
6   2   lion   0
7   2  tiger   1
8   2   bear   2
```